# Which "init" method does segue call on UIViewController?

Tags: ios, object, segue

Bear with me here, when we link one `UIViewController` to another one with a segue, which "init" method does the segue use to initiate the new `UIViewController`? Is it "initWithCoder" ? or something else? I need to know because I need to modify the init method that segue uses to initiate the `UIViewController`.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is this method

`initWithCoder`

I think this solution is better
You write some common code in

```
-(void)setUp{
//Set up
    }
```

Then you put this code in every **initMethod**:

```
-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        [self setUp];
    }
    return self;
}
-(instancetype)init{
    if (self = [super init]) {
         [self setUp];
    }
    return self;
}
//Also other init method
```

Comment: So should I just add my implementation for just that init method? And how do you know that, is there anyway to check which init is called by default on other objects?

Comment: I will update my answer to give you a better solution